# how to use Layout to display the result get from XML

Tags: android, listview

I am A new guy in Android. I try to develop a list that can show the song name and author at the same line. The source data is from a online XML file

The following is the code I try to use in my program. 
However, I only be able to display the author name in the list. 
I would to ask how I should modify the code so that I can show the song name and author at the same line in the list?

The Format of online XML file I try to read

```
<recipes>
<song>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>Sing A Song</title>
    <songs_author>ACM</songs_author>
</song>
<song>
    <id>2</id>
    <title>DO Re Me</title>
    <songs_author>BBC/songs_author>
</song>
</recepies>
```

src/com.mobile/SongsActivity

```
package com.mobile;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class SongsActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    protected static final int DIALOG_KEY = 0;
    ListView mListView;
    Button mClear;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        this.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

        setContentView(R.layout.Songs);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);


        LoadRecipesTask1 mLoadRecipesTask = new LoadRecipesTask1();
        mLoadRecipesTask.execute("http://123.com/mobile/Songs_list.php");          



        mClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        mClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mListView.setAdapter(null);
            }
        });

    }



    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Datum datum = (Datum) mListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://123.com/mobile/Songs.php?Songsid=" + datum.getId());
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }

    public static ArrayList<Datum> parse(String url) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        final ArrayList<Datum> results = new ArrayList<Datum>();

        URL input = new URL(url);

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

        xpp.setInput(input.openStream(), null);
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        String currentTag = null;
        Integer id = null;
        String title = null;
        String Songs_author = null;
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                currentTag = xpp.getName();
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                if ("id".equals(currentTag)) {
                    id = Integer.valueOf(xpp.getText());
                }
                if ("title".equals(currentTag)) {
                    title = xpp.getText();
                }
                if ("Songs_author".equals(currentTag)) {
                    Songs_author = xpp.getText();
                }
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                if ("song".equals(xpp.getName())) {
                    results.add(new Datum(id, title, Songs_author));
                }
            }
            eventType = xpp.next();
        }
        return results;
    }

    protected class LoadRecipesTask1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Datum>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            SongsActivity.this.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Datum> doInBackground(String... urls) {
            ArrayList<Datum> datumList = new ArrayList<Datum>();
            try {
                datumList = parse(urls[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return datumList;
        }




        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Datum> result) {





            mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Datum>(SongsActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, result));
            //SongsActivity.this.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
        }
    }



}
```

src/com.mobile/Datum

```
package com.mobile;

public class Datum {

    int id;
    String title;
    String songs_author;

    public Datum(int id, String title, String songs_author) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.songs_author= songs_author;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return songs_author;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String get Songs_author() {
        return Songs_author;
    }

}
```

res/layout/songs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <Button android:text="Refresh 1" android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
                <Button android:text="Clear" android:id="@+id/button3"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
        <ListView android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

res/layout/list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

Comment: Code is missing and you should use ListView.

Comment: I have added the code.
I know that I should use ListView but I am not sure how to implement it... can u help me more instruction?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make Custom List View using array adapter.

refer this example..

http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

Answer (score 0):

The web is full of tutorial and example of ListView using Custom Adapter. You will have to spend some time trying to learn them. No shortcuts. You can one of them [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) or you can select one of the books from Amazon.